# memory leak on closing GUI

Tags: wxpython

I'm developing a GUI and everything is going well, except that when I close it the following appears in my terminal and I fear that it may affect the enduser:

```
swig/python detected a memory leak of type 'wxWizard *', no destructor found.
```

How do I prevent this memory leak from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the wizard isn't getting closed correctly. Make sure you call the wizard's Destroy() method when you exit the wizard, regardless of whether or not the user finishes the wizard.

You should be able to do this by catching the wizard's Finish and Cancel button events. You could also catch EVT_CLOSE and Destroy the wizard in that event handler. Please note that if you this, you will also need to call the frame's Destroy method to get the frame to close properly.

Comment: Please create a small runnable example that demonstrates the issue. Also include what OS, wxPython and Python versions you are using

Comment: Hi `Mike`. I have called the `Destroy()` method for the wizard for each of the separate apps (which are functions I have implemented in my `TestPanel` class), as well as incorporating most of the `run.py` code. After defining my `class LoginDialog()` object, I immediately copy-pasted the `class RunDemoApp()` object in the `run.py`module, making all the relevant package imports. From a tip you gave me earlier, I deduced that if I explicitly included the code in `run.py` I would not need the `runTest` function. As always, thanks for the guidance `Mike`. Your blog is great by the way!

Comment: This is a complicated wizard with many features I'm developing for a healthcare client for creating cohorts and analyzing incidence rates as well as doing signal detection, so creating a small runnable example may be hard but I'll try if I fail to solve this by end of day. Be that as it may, I am using Mac OS X Mavericks, wxPython version 3.0 (cocoa) and python 2.7.6. Thanks once again.

Comment: You might find this link useful too if you are using demo code: http://wiki.wxpython.org/Using%20wxPython%20Demo%20Code

Comment: Thanks Mike. Just checked it out and it is very informative, especially for a relative wxPython neophyte like me

Comment: Mike, I had another question but it can't fit here because of it's length so I'm just going to go ahead and ask it as a separate question and hope that you see it and can lead me in the right direction. It concerns threading.